# Concatenation string with const char(result GetComputerName) on C++

Tags: c++, concatenation, strcpy, strcat

**Need**: Concatenate the result of the `function GetComputerName (nameBuf)` with the command to open the Chormium.

**Objective**: Create a new profile with the name of the machine that is being carried out the installation.

**Problem**: I do not know how I can accomplish this concatenation've tried to accomplish with `strcpy` and `strcat` without success.

**Here my code:**

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE inst,HINSTANCE prev,LPSTR cmd,int show)
{

    //Close phpdesktop.exe
    WinExec("taskkill /F /IM phpdesktop.exe", SW_HIDE);
    //Sleep
    Sleep(500);
    //Open phpdesktop.exe mini server 
    WinExec("phpdesktop.exe -S 127.0.0.1:54007 -t www -c php.ini", SW_HIDE);
    //Sleep    
    Sleep(500);

    //Get computer name
    TCHAR nameBuf[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 2];
    DWORD nameBufSize;

    nameBufSize = sizeof nameBuf - 1;
    if (GetComputerName(nameBuf, &nameBufSize) == TRUE) 
    {
       //How to make the concatenation result nameBuf GetComputerName function with the command of Chromium.                  
       WinExec(strcpy("chromium\\ChromiumPortable -app=http://127.0.0.1:54007/ --profile-directory=", nameBuf), SW_HIDE);
    }

    //Return 
    return 0;
}
```

--

Pastbin: http://pastebin.com/N1eyAfGV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to use a second buffer you acn try this

```
THAR nameBuf[254 + 2]={0};
DWORD nameBufSize;
strcpy(nameBuf,"chromium\\ChromiumPortable -app=http://127.0.0.1:54007/ --profile-directory=");
nameBufSize = sizeof nameBuf - 1;
int index = strlen(nameBuf);
if (GetComputerName(&nameBuf[index], &nameBufSize) == TRUE) 
{
   WinExec(nameBuf, SW_HIDE);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`strcpy` into a `const char *` invokes *undefined behavior*:

```
std::string s = "chromium\\ChromiumPortable ...";
s += nameBuf;

WinExec(s.c_str(), SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: with this solution I could not apply ... But I believe it is my fault. I appreciate your help friend!

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
TCHAR command[1024];
strcpy(command, "chromium\\ChromiumPortable -app=http://127.0.0.1:54007/ --profile-directory=");
strcat(command,nameBuf);
WinExec(command, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: You second `strcpy` should be `strcat`, isn't it?

Comment: The first must be `strcpy` since `command` is not initialized yet.

Comment: The example is correct, the first is `strcpy` not `strcat` :-)